# como crear el cuerpo de un thread y usarlo en google test

Tags: c++, hilos

lo primero, perdon por si el titulo no es el mas apropiado.

Estoy tratando de escribir un test de google, que lance varios threads, a modo de testlogging. Esta seria la funcion que ejecutarian los threads.

```
    void log(std::vector<int>& A, severity_t severity){
         for(size_t scanA(0);scanA!=A.size();++scanA){
             switch(severity){
                    case severity_t::debug:
                         //do something
                         break;
                    case severity_t::info:
                         //do something
                         break;
                    default:
                         break;
             }
          }
    }
```

El test esta escrito como:

```
TEST(testLog, testA){
    //Inicializo A
    //Hago un thread para cada severity:
        std::thread logDebug(std::bind(&log,A,severity_t::debug));
        std::thread logInfo(std::bind(&log,A,severity_t::info));
        //...
    //Y hago el join para cada uno
        logDebug.join();
        logInfo.join();
        //...
    //Hago lo necesario para obtener resultados. y termino el test.
    }
```

Estoy compilando en un redHat con gcc 4.4.7 y con -std=c++0x por obligación.
Y el resultado de la compilación es:
**error: no matching function for call to 'bind( < unresolved overloaded function type > , std::vector< int >&, severity_t)'**

Un saludo.

Comment: Hay algo que no está bien en ese código. En principio faltan los ; (punto y coma) al final de la creación de los threads, y tampoco es esa la forma de crearlos. Puedes consultar una referencia en http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Comment: Lo de los punto y coma ha sido un typo al escribir el mensaje. En cuanto a la referencia q me apuntas, tb lo he probado y obtengo el mismo error

Comment: Si no usas bind(), no deberías tener un mensaje de error sobre bind(). Intenta nuevamente.

Comment: Cierto, perdón, en ese caso el error q obtengo es que el constructor no es el adecuado. Ya q el que me apuntas es xa c++11. Tb he probado con std::ref xa las referencias. Muchas gracias x tus respuestas

Comment: Tienes ahí un problema adicional. `-std=c++0x` dice al compilador que use C++11, pero también es probable que la versión gcc 4.4.7 no haya implementado std::threads correctamente (o de alguna forma que sirva para algo). Yo intentaría invocar std::thread() con una función sin argumentos a ver qué dice.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema.

El error es claro y cristalino, pero tal vez no estás familiarizado por estar en inglés, permíteme traducirlo:

> error: no coincide ninguna función para llamar a 'bind( < tipo de función sobrecargada no resuelto >, std::vector< int >&, severity_t)'

El error te está diciendo que hay más de una función con el mismo nombre (función sobrecargada) y con sólo el nombre no sabe distinguir cuál usar. Puedes ver el mismo error con este ejemplo simplificado:

```
void log(int){}
void log(double){}

int main( void )
{
    auto b1 = std::bind(log, 1); // < tipo de función sobrecargada no resuelto >

    return 0;
}
```

#### Solución.

Dado que el nombre `log` es ambiguo debido a las sobrecargas, deberás decirle al compilador qué versión de la función `log` quieres usar, puedes usar una conversión para ello:

```
void log(int){}
void log(double){}

int main( void )
{
    using log_int = void(int); // Alias al tipo 'función que recibe int'

    auto b1 = std::bind(static_cast<log_int *>(log), 1);
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //          queremos usar la version que recibe int

    return 0;
}
```

#### Nota.

En tú código sólo has puesto una versión de `log`, así que no te puedo ayudar a deducir el tipo que quieres desambiguar, pero posiblemente sería algo así:

```
using log_t = void(std::vector<int>&, severity_t);

std::thread logDebug(std::bind(static_cast<log_t *>(log),A,severity_t::debug));
std::thread logInfo(std::bind(static_cast<log_t *>(log),A,severity_t::info));
```